# How do you do the Cheryl problem (the one about her birthday)?

Tags: logic, recreational-mathematics

Albert and Bernard just became friends with Cheryl, and they want to know when her birthday is. Cheryl gives them a list of 10 possible dates.

May 15 
June 17
July 14
August 14
May 16
June 18
July 16
August 15
May 19
August 17

Cheryl then tells Albert and Bernard separately the month and the day of her birthday respectively.

Albert says that he does not know when Cheryl’s birthday is, but he knows Bernard doesn’t know either.
Bernard says that he first didn’t, but know he knew.
Then Albert says he knows when her birthday is.

So how do you know when is her birthday? (Search Cheryl riddle on the internet) I don’t get the explanation.

Comment: [Numberphile's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emiMj8cCL5E) and [James Grime's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3Nzkae_TRU) are both good explanations.

Comment: Even after watching the linked videos you *still* don't get it?  Any explanation we give will be effectively the same as their explanations.  The whole point is that what information they share eliminates some of the remaining possibilities for the other person from that other person's perspective.

Comment: See also [this interactive page](http://mark.github.io/olympiad/) where you can see why each of the other possible answers fail, getting to see some of the possible thoughts running through each person's head.